# PHP, HTML, Drupal 7 variable

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I have html code and would like to insert a node title into it (juste at the "label" place), so this is what i have done:

```
<?php
$nid = 4;
$node = node_load($nid);
$title = $node->title;
?>

var node = 
{
label : $title
};
```

But it doesn't show up in drupal. Have I done something wrong?

Thank you,

Jamie

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to print out a php variable into HTML, in which case you'll need to enclose it in php tags and use the print function, like so:

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```